# Finding nested file path in ruby

Tags: ruby

I wish to search for a file with a qualified file name such as the following:

```
"git_hub_repo_app/SampleProj.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"
```

- The first part, here `"git_hub_repo_app"`, is stored in a variable called `location`.
- `"SampleProj"` is a placeholder that represents any string.
- `.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` is fixed and given.

I tried searching for files having the following path:

```
location + '/*.xcodeproj/' + '/project.pbxproj'
```

but was unable to locate a file.

Comment: `'/*.xcodeproj/' + '/project.pbxproj' #=> "/*.xcodeproj//project.pbxproj"`. Try `'/*.xcodeproj/' + 'project.pbxproj' #=>  "/*.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"`, or, better, simply `'/*.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj'`.

Answer (score 0):

### Use File#dirname

One way to get the directory name from a given *location* value is to pass it to [File#dirname](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/File.html#method-c-dirname). For example:

```
location = 'git_hub_repo_app/SampleProj.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj'
File.dirname location
#=> "git_hub_repo_app/SampleProj.xcodeproj"
```